# Build Amazon Affiliate Link Swift

Tags: swift, url, affiliate

I would like to be able to build an Amazon-Affiliate link, when a "normal" Amazon `URL` is given.

I tried using this structure:

```
http://www.amazon.com/dp/{ASIN}/?tag={trackingId}
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15066918/11968226).

This is how I try to create the `URL`:

```
func getAmazonAffiliateLink() -> URL? {
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([\\w-]+/)?(dp|gp/product)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})"),
       let match = regex.firstMatch(in: self, range: NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self)),
       let asinMatchRange = Range(match.range(at: 4), in: self) {
        let asin = self[asinMatchRange]
        let partnerId = "wishlists07-21"
        let affiliateLink = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/\(asin)/?tag=\(partnerId)"
        return URL(string: affiliateLink)
    } else {
        return nil
    }

}
```

But this gives me this `URL` for example:

> [https://www.amazon.com/dp/b085sp5sxh/?tag=wishlists07-21](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/b085sp5sxh)

And as you can see for yourself, it is not working...

What am I missing here? How can I build affiliate links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the initial link you're testing with is probably bad -- in other words, when I remove your wishlist tag and just try the basic Amazon link, it still fails.

But, with a valid Amazon product link, it seems to work.  Here's what I did in a Playground:

```
extension String {
    func getAmazonAffiliateLink() -> URL? {
        if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([\\w-]+/)?(dp|gp/product)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})"),
           let match = regex.firstMatch(in: self, range: NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self)),
           let asinMatchRange = Range(match.range(at: 4), in: self) {
            let asin = self[asinMatchRange]
            let partnerId = "wishlists07-21"
            let affiliateLink = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/\(asin)/?tag=\(partnerId)"
            return URL(string: affiliateLink)
        } else {
            return nil
        }

    }
}

"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0863ZGP2R/ref=fs_a_ipadt2_us0".getAmazonAffiliateLink()
```

Which yields the result of `https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0863ZGP2R/?tag=wishlists07-21` which is a working Amazon link.

Comment: you are absolutely right... I called `.lowercased()` on the URL before. Don't ask me why :) Never mind, it is working now. Thanks :)